# Vote to "Accepted Answer" if questioner has abandoned their question without accepting an answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

There are a lot of questions that have received many answers but either the question owner abandoned the question or did not bother to accept an answer. In such a case, will it be an appropriate alternate to accept an answer using the number of votes?

Currently the answer is marked as 'Question owner accepted this as the best answer', but if it gets elected by number of votes, it can be 'Community accepted this as the best answer'.

How I think it should work is like this: Person A asks a question and receives answers but they don't accept an answer. After one month time, the system automatically assigns an answer as 'Accepted' on greater number of votes at that time.

In case Person A returns and accepts another answer, Community's accepted answer can either change to that or both can have 'Accepted by Person A' and 'Accepted by Community' status. Or Person A's accepted answer will replace the Community's accepted answer.

This is just a suggestion, if it has already been discussed, please let me know so I can delete the question. I have searched but couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this has been brought up for discussion here; nearest I can find is [this old post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/117/22). Similar ideas *have* been brought up (and declined) on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/132874), however.

And in all honesty, I'm not sure this would really accomplish anything anyway. The main advantage of the "Accepted Answer" system is that it bypasses voting; if the questioner found one answer that was actually useful *despite* not being well-voted for whatever reason, it would allow that answer to be displayed at the top of the list.

If there is no accepted answer, the top-voted answer is *already* displayed at the top of the list. Whether or not it's "accepted" won't change that.

Comment: I read the linked question and answer and what you said, both makes sense. Like Robert said, it kind of doesn't give me 'closure' when I see those questions without an accepted answer. But you are right.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I doubt the accept rate has a significant effect on graduation at all, really. As far as Stack Exchange is concerned, a question is still considered "answered" as long as it has at least one *upvoted* answer. (see: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/). As long as people are voting properly, it's already a solved problem.

Comment: I see so apparently i still have to learn a lot to understand how this works!